# Initializer expression list treated as compound expression vector

Tags: c++, function, vector, ostream

I cant seem to get this one figured out, i'm trying to call a vector to a function and geting the errors
initializer expression list treated as compound expression
 cannot convert `Vector<int>` to `int` in initialization.

the function:

```
int print_vector(ostream& os, vector<int> f, vector<int> g, vector<int> h)
{
    for(int cnt=0; cnt!=10;cnt++){
         os << f[cnt];
    };
    for(int cnt=0; cnt!=11;cnt++){
        os << g[cnt];
    };
    for(int cnt=0; cnt!=20;cnt++){
        os << h[cnt];
    };

    return 0;
 }
```

the call

```
int print_vector(&out,v,vec, vector);
```

the initilization(this happened before the call)

```
ostream out();
    vector<int> v(10);
for(int cnt=0;cnt!=10;cnt++){
    v[cnt] = 99+cnt;
};

vector<int> vec(11);
for(int cnt=0;cnt!=11;cnt++){
    vec[cnt] = 99+cnt;
};

vector<int> vector(20);
for(int cnt=0;cnt!=20;cnt++){
    vector[cnt] = 99+cnt;
};
```

Comment: Rename your variable `vector` here: `vector(20);` to a different name - it conflicts with the template `std::vector<>`

Comment: Yes, and there are various other problems. You can't create an `ostream` object like that, for two reasons: a) The empty pair of parentheses means the compiler does not parse this correctly as a constructor call, b) An `ostream` cannot be constructed without a buffer. Secondly, when you call `print_vector`, don't put a type (`int`) in front of the function name.

Comment: Oh and it's strange that you take the `vector` arguments by value in the definition of your function. Why not const-references?

Comment: if not type int for the function what should i put in its place?

Comment: Nothing. You need a type only in the declaration and definition of the function, but not when you call it.